# Length of the curve defined by $y=6 x^{3/2} - 7$ from $x=1$ to $x = 9\;$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the length of the curve defined by $y=6 x^{3/2} - 7$ from $x=1$ to $x = 9$.

I need help with this section. I would really appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: Where did you get stuck? Did you have trouble computing the integral in the arc length formula?

Comment: I just realized it's arclength :-D I know how to do this.

Comment: Compute $L=\int_1^9 \sqrt{1+ (y')^2 }\,dx$

Comment: @DavidMitra, Yes, thank you (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the formula

$$ s = \int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{1+y'(x)^2} dx $$

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why I was blanking out. I know how to do this already. Thank you for answering though (-:

Comment: @Ceelos: You are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Compute $y'$ and then compute the length $\mathcal{l}$:

$$\mathcal{l} =\int_1^9 \sqrt{1 + (y'(x))^2}dx$$

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$
y=6x^{(3/2)} -7$$
Let $\mathcal{L}$ denote the length of the curve. We can calculate $\mathcal{L}$ by
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L} &= \int_1^9 \sqrt{1+(y')^2} \, dx
\\ &= \int_1^9 \sqrt{1+((6x^{(3/2)} -7)')^2} \, dx
\\ &= \int_1^9 \sqrt{1+(9x^{(1/2)})^2} \, dx
\\ &= \int_1^9 \sqrt{1+81x} \, dx 
\\ &= \Bigl[\frac{2}{243} (1+81x)^{3/2} \Bigr]_1^9 \approx 156.22
\end{align} 
See [Wolfram Alpha for the integration](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20sqrt%281%2b81%2ax%29%20from%201%20to%209).